# Discord JS Welcome message canvas issue

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Good Morning everyone!,

I'm using this code to start learning welcome message in canvas with my discord bot as shown below:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Slightly smaller text placed above the member's display name
    ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('Welcome to the server,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);

    // Add an exclamation point here and below
    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, attachment);
});
```

But when I join the discord with special character like this:  it doesn't appear correctly in the canvas image as shown below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3GPX.png)

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/uCjvef3

Comment: still not working for me :(

I only have installed the canvas as it says in the guide  "npm i canvas"  (version 2.6.1) and the discord library (v12.5.1). I am missing a package ? That would be the reason that i cannot see the characters?

Answer (score 0):

use the [Fancy Text Converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancy-text-converter) Node Module to convert the text to normal